# Cooking Ramen noodles in broth or not?

Tags: noodles, broth, ramen

I was wondering if there’s a downside in cooking ramen noodles directly in the broth it will served in. From the recipes I see, ramen noodles are cooked in slightly salted water and then incorporated into the hot broth.

With instant ramen noodle, cooking directly in the broth seems more common.

Any advice? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Usually it's best to cook dried noodles in boiling water, and drain and rinse them in cold water when they are done. This does a couple of things:

- helps ensure that the noodle is equally cooked all the way through (instead of getting overcooked on the outside by the time the centre is cooked).
- by using separate water, you don't fill your broth with starch, which would adversely affect the taste, colour and consistency.

If you want to add the noodles directly to the broth, I would recommend rinsing them in cold water first (like you would with rice) until the water runs clear. This will prevent excess starch from being added to your dish.

You could also try adding a stock cube to the water that you boil the noodles in, if your goal is simply to make the noodles more flavourful.

Comment: Thank you! That seem like a set of very sound advices. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Don't rinse the noodles! Good way to ensure they're flavorless, and nothing sticks to them because all the gluten on the outside has been washed off.

Comment: @DwigtF. That is a very common mistake people make when making pasta's like Spaghetti! Sauce doesn't stick, and unless thoroughly dried, you get a puddle of water on your plate.

Comment: Since these are noodles that will be put into broth to make ramen, the downsides of rinsing probably aren't as significant.

Answer (score 0):

Ramen noodles are to be prepared differently from pasta! Higher quality ramen noodles are made with seasonings. Even the cheap ramen noodles cone with a highly salty seasoning packet. And the broth that you make or buy is much more salty than any Italian pasta sauce. Just boil your ramen noodles in water. No need to rinse your ramen noodles, unless you par boil batches of them first. Just reduce the boiling time by a minute or two (depending on the cooking times of the original directions). Then rinse and cover and refrigerate. You can save them in individual servings and then put in boiling water for a minute or two right before serving!